# Firebase push notifications stop working for some users

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS and Android app which uses Firebase Cloud messaging for push notifications. And PHP for back-end (to send requests to firebase).
Some users have a problem. If they reinstall the app from scratch, they get push notifications 1-2 days. Then they just stop to receive any push notifications.

I got their firebase tokens and tried to send notifications directly from Firebase console. And they don't get it. But Firebase tells me that push successfully sent.

Checked iPhone's settings - notifications are enabled.

Can someone help me? What should I do to understand where is the problem?

Comment: i am having same issue when the user re-installs the app, push notification is not working for me also. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are updating the FCM token whenever it is getting refreshed.

Comment: @Shruti i am sending the token still not working, trying with firebase console also.

Comment: Have you implemented `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)`

Comment: @Shruti nope, I get token from `Messaging.messaging().fcmToken`. I think it's the same.

Comment: @MikeTimashov yes but this delegate method gets called everytime your token is refreshed. So you need to fetch a new token from here and update it

Comment: What matters is when are you fetching token from Messaging.messaging().fcmToken??

Comment: I get it each time user opens the app. I will try to get it from delegate method. Maybe it helps.

Comment: same issue, app was receiving push notifications but suddenly it stopped receiving notifications. Did not even touch the code but still this behavior. Firebase team should put some efforts into this bug